# Phonegap + Cordova does not work on latest Android versions

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, phonegap

I have an application developed in Phonegap+Cordova that has stopped working in recent versions of Android. Does anyone know how I can migrate the phongap part fully to cordova and if that would resolve the malfunction?

I found out with the malfunction recently that phonegap is no longer supported. I need to make the application run on the latest versions of Android, 12++.